# How to view diff of a forked github project

Tags: git, github, diff, git-fork

I have forked a project on github and need to have a set of changes I made since I forked, in diff format.

If you wonder - I've forked Apache httpd and I'm changing some code in core. Currently I'm not commiting any changes, running git diff, and use its output as a patch against vanilla httpd sources in an RPM building process. It is, of course, wrong, but I don't know how to do it properly. All I know is I need a diff in the end.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Online solution:

> ```
> get /repos/{owner}/{repo}/compare/{base}...{head}
> ```

The ["compare two commits" API](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#compare-two-commits) does support multiple repositories:

> Both `:base` and `:head` must be branch names in `:repo`.
> To compare branches across other repositories in the same network as `:repo`, use the format `<USERNAME>:branch`.

Example:

https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/compare/master...abejpn:master

Or with a GitHub URL:

https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/compare/master...abejpn:master

---

Original answer 2010:

- Add the original GitHub repo (the one you have forked) as a remote one on your local repo.
  (**`git remote add mainRepo github_url`**)
- **`git fetch mainRepo`** to get the latest changes from that original "mainRepo".
- **`git log HEAD..mainRepo/master`** will show you all your changes between the latest on mainRepo master branch and your current branch.
  **`git diff HEAD..mainRepo/master`** would display it in diff format.

In [learn.GitHub](http://learn.github.com/p/diff.html#what_a_merge_would_introduce):

```
git diff mainRepo/master...HEAD
```

would list all your changes since you have forked from `mainRepo`:

> This will not compare the last ‘master’ branch snapshot and the last ‘dev’ snapshot - it will instead compare the common ancestor of both with ‘dev’. That will tell you what changed since the branch point.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves my issue. I definitely need to spend some time to understand git philosophy deeper.

Comment: +1. If I may add two notes: I believe the HEAD parts are unnecessary if you are currently on the head. Also, `git difftool mainrepo/master` and `git difftool ..mainrepo/master` are useful if you want to view the changes in your configured difftool.

Comment: How to view diffs of a forked project via TortoiseGit - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7297491/968003

Comment: *`fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD..upstream/master'`* and *`fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD...upstream/master'`*... Reversing arguments made no difference. Yet another simple task made difficult.

Comment: @jww do you have defined upstream in your remotes (`git remote -v`)? DO you have created a branch named `upstream/master`? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26046933/6309), or a tag (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35980056/6309)?

Answer (score 15):

This is an old question, but I just found a very nice method to **get a patch or diff file directly from Github**.

When you are on your fork, there is a **"Compare" link**. Using that you are getting to the compare view.

Example

```
https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/compare/master...beat2:master
```

Now you can **manually add either ".diff" or ".patch" to the end of this url**, and you get the file directly in your browser.

Example

```
https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/compare/master...beat2:master.diff
```

Source: https://github.com/blog/967-github-secrets

Answer (score 7):

If you push a branch that tracks the "upstream" repo to your repository, then you can see the diff in github itself, too:

```
 git remote add mainRepo github_url
 git fetch mainRepo
 git branch main_repo_master mainRepo/master
 git push origin main_repo_master
```

Then see it online like this:

https://github.com/rdp/mplayer-svn/compare/master…main_repo_master

ref: http://betterlogic.com/roger/2012/04/github-compare-commits

Answer (score 2):

Get parent/fork point sha1: `git merge-base master HEAD`
Get diff: `git diff <sha1>`

Or in one command: `git difftool $(git merge-base master HEAD)`

Which is the same as sugar command: `git diff master...HEAD`