# Git: How to check for remote changes within a directory

Tags: git, file, directory

Given that Git is very SHA-1 friendly, I would surmise that it is possible to easily check for this scenario:

-I have a repo with a directory **foo/** somewhere within it. 
-Someone on some other computer makes a change to **foo**'s contents (including nested subdirectories), and pushes the change to the repo.

My guess is that I will have to do a fetch and check if there is some difference between the SHA-1 for my directory and the SHA-1 of the remote directory, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Basically... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792989/how-to-view-diff-of-a-forked-github-project/3793113#3793113

Comment: What you think is MD5 is actually SHA-1. :)

Comment: @Bombe Thanks for the correction, fixed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can simply use `git diff --quiet` and check its exit code:

```
git fetch # get latest code from upstream
git diff --quiet master..origin/master -- foo/ || echo 'directory differ'
```

`diff --quiet` will exit with 1 when there are differences and exit with an error code of 0 the objects (blob or tree) are identical