# GitHub: Would my Fork get updated when the master is changing?

Tags: git, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I update a forked project, on git, to the original/master copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297486/can-i-update-a-forked-project-on-git-to-the-original-master-copy)

I've created a Fork as I would like to change some of the code in the master project: https://github.com/DennisMadsen/PullToRefreshView. I would like my Fork and its repository to get updated, when any new files are pushed into the master repository. Would that happen automatically or what should I do?

Comment: Also a duplicate of [When a GitHub fork gets updated how do I keep my fork current while I still have a pending pull request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673207/when-a-github-fork-gets-updated-how-do-i-keep-my-fork-current-while-i-still-have)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It won't update automatically, but you can use git to pull the changes from the master repository. See documentation here: http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/

Comment: Thank you, but I'm using the GitHub for Mac to clone my repositories. Do you know if I can do this inside the application instead of using the command line?

Comment: Specifically, the point "Pull in upstream changes". However, the commands given there don't include pushing up to GitHub after the merge, which you will need to do to keep your public repository up to date.

Comment: GitHub for Mac doesn't support what you want to do. From their documentation: "GitHub for Mac does not support multiple Git remotes. We will only work with the origin remote. If you wish to push & pull to other remotes, we suggest that you use the command line client."
In order to pull changes from the upstream, you need a secondary remote.