# When a GitHub fork gets updated how do I keep my fork current while I still have a pending pull request?

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a fork of a project and I send a pull request. But the repo I forked from gets updated when I still have a pending push. How do I keep upto date without losing my changes from the pull request?

Comment: Keep merging from the master?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commits from your pull request should be in a different branch.

So you can simply `git pull upstream` and `git merge --ff-only upstream/master` (ensure that you are in your master branch first: `git checkout master`) to bring your master branch up to date (assuming the original repo is in a remote called `upstream`)

Comment: Can you suggest a good GUI GitHub client for mac? I'm not great with command line

Comment: You should really get used to the CLI first before using a gui client. After that, consider using the official one from github: http://mac.github.com/

Comment: The only problem with that is that client is buggy as hell But thanks