# How to update GitHub forked repository using TortoiseGIT?

Tags: git, repository, fork, tortoisegit

I forked a repository, made some changes, submitted a pull request, and had my changes accepted. Now several months later my branch doesn't have any of the changes other contributors have made.

I've found this info: [How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-to-update-github-forked-repository)

Which was somewhat useful, but I'm using TortoiseGIT, not the command line GIT. So these instructions don't work for me. How would I manage this with TortoiseGIT?

Charles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your branch has been accepted and merge into the original repo, you don't need it anymore.

You can simply update your local master to reflect the original repo master branch, by pulling it.
See "[Can I update a forked project, on git, to the original/master copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297486/can-i-update-a-forked-project-on-git-to-the-original-master-copy)", for TortoiseGit instruction.

The TortoiseGit **`pull`** dialog box will allow you to chose the remote repo from which you want to pull.