# How can I keep a git fork updated?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I update a forked project, on git, to the original/master copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297486/can-i-update-a-forked-project-on-git-to-the-original-master-copy)

Let's say I fork a project, and then clone it down to my machine.

At this point, `git pull`, as well as `git fetch` and `git rebase origin/branch_name`, refer to my forked repository. If I wanted to rebase to the original repository's master, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the original repo as a remote

```
git remote add upstream git@github.com:<OriginalUser>/<OriginalRepo>.git
```

then rebase from there

```
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/master
```

Comment: how nice, a downvote with no comment.