# Git workflow with upstream and origin and Heroku staging and production

Tags: git

I am having some doubts on a suggested workflow for this situation:

I have two Github repositories, one upstream and a forked one (origin).  From my local repository I keep pushing to origin and doing pull requests to upstream.  When I think that everything is correct to test on staging, I push my develop branch to the remote Heroku staging.

My question is: My local develop branch is up to date with my origin, but what I really want is to push what is in upstream (because it is actually where every potential developer code is). What is the correct way of doing so? Shall I create another local branch develop-upstream that is "tracking" the develop branch in upstream?

Comment: So you wanna keep your fork up-to-date with the upstream? This is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534677/how-can-i-keep-a-git-fork-updated/14534703#14534703

Comment: Have you looked into [Heroku labs pipeline](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-pipelines)?