# Change git remote origin

Tags: git, github

On github, I've forked a project from its original source `original/project-name` so now I have a remote repo on github `myusername/project-name`. I would now like to switch my github repo to use a contributors fork `contributor/project-name`. How can I do this?

Comment: Use `git remote set-url origin [NEW_REMOTE_URL]`

Comment: Something I do when working with forked repos is to create another remote, for easy pull, and keep origin to easy push.

Comment: @askvictor any luck with the proposed answers?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella - I don't want to change the remote of my local repository - I want to change the remote repo to a different fork

Answer (score 7):

As already noted in the comments, it's as simple as

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/contributor/project-name.git
```

An alternative you may want to consider is to create a second remote for the fork.

```
git remote add fork https://github.com/contributor/project-name.git
```

If you want to keep the fork up-to-date with the original repo, you can refer to my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534677/how-can-i-keep-a-git-fork-updated/14534703#14534703).

Answer (score 1):

Gabriele's answer provides the quickest and most concise option, but you could alternatively edit the .git/config file to change the remote.  Possibly a better choice would be to add another remote all together as done by

```
git remote add REMOTE_NAME_HERE REMOTE_URL_HERE
```

i.e.:

```
git remote add test https://github.com/username/test-project.git
```

where "test" becomes the name of your new remote.  You would then push to the remote repo using "test" instead of "origin"

```
git push -u test BRANCH_NAME
```